Designing 4 apps with the same UX but each app is for a different customer, how do I design the apps to differintiate between them?
The company I work for has 4 apps for different customers, but the ux is the same in all of them (maybe a few categories is removed between the apps)
Combining to a one app is not possible, We talked about using a different accent color in each app but its not the best Idea.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to deal with this situation?

Different companies have their own set of branding colors. What if you allow companies to customize and set their brand colors for example on app header?

They dont have a brand identity per say.
Their set of colors is only two, a black one and yellow. they are their main ones, but wish to change colors for each app so the user will be able to know the difference, and if doing so we lose the brand identity. so im trying to think of a solution.

Well, you have an example right in front of you. If you look at the design of the different Stack Exchange sites you can get ideas: the same app/different users, and there are quite a few more than four .

The corporate elements remain exactly the same: background color, typography, icons, icon color, layout, main logo, etc.
The logos of each application change
The background color of the header banner changes, and is the same in the footer
In some, the background color of the page changes, like in English SE
The background and border color of the CTAs changes
The color of the typography in key elements changes
Some sites have a background image like Spanish SE



WOW didnt notice that but amazing example for me, thank you!

There is no need to have a different accent color on each app; that will ruin your branding. If there is no brand identity at the moment, then perhaps it's time to lay the groundwork. Brand colors come from the org values as well as the audience it caters to. e.g. It is hard to imagine Lego in indigo color. It is not necessary to have the primary brand color and the primary accent color in the app as the same. But once established, you will realize that even with slight differences in the UX once in a while the app will look and feel the same.
From the description, it looks like the difference between the products is similar to paid subscription levels - e.g. free, premium, luxury – if only 'categories' are being removed or hidden. Given that the UX remains the same should mean that core navigation and page layout more or less remain the same. Question is – what value do you derive from differentiating between the products? Unless the user group is children under 13 years of age and you need to have bright, playful colors, there should be no need to deviate from primary branding.
